# Unstable gaming performance i3-3225 + RX550

Tags: windows, graphics-card, gpu, amd-radeon, intel-core-i3

I recently (2018) bought new graphics card Radeon RX550 (2GB, 7000MHz) to my old PC(bought 2012).

Other components are:
i3 3225 (3,3 GHz, 2 cores/4hreads)
8GB RAM (DDR3)
Z77-D3H motherboard
500W power source

I tested few games and result was like "random". For instance, tried to run Mafia 2 video tests (something like 2 minutes demo that measures fps) and results were:
average 55 fps, then I rerun test with same settings and got average 10 fps, after rerun again with same settings, get 30 fps average. I found similair results in other games as well. Weird is that If I see utilisation of my CPU and GPU, its is far from 100% utilisation(Windows task manager) - GPU fan is on low speed etc. Why it sometimes run ok and sometimes not?

How that is possible? I expect that with same computer, same settings I expect to get same results. Tried that on fresh installed Windows 10 and Windows 7, so no other programs are interrupting mentioned tests. Newest drivers were installed.

I do not expect to resolve that problem, I will return that GPU most probably, but Im interested if somebody can explain what is theory behind those random test results. What is happening there or how to figure? Is problematic that PC components are like 6 years old and GPU is new one? Is that game engine specific problem?

Thank you !!

Comment: Sounds pretty unusual indeed. Mafia II isn't known for being the best performer, but still, such fluctuations are pretty unusual. Have you tried a synthetic test like Heaven or Firestrike? Where did you purchase the GPU? Could you post a GPU-Z screenshot? Also, just to make sure, the display cable is plugged into the GPU and not the motherboard, yes?

Comment: Just ran Heaven test, its result both with GPU-Z screenshot are uploaded in link. I am 100% sure that I use RX550 instead my integrated graphics (I disabled integ. gpu in bios). GPU has been purchased in local well known shop with warranty - this should not be problem. One thing that came to my mind when I was looking to GPU-Z - it tells that I use PCIe x8, instead of x16 - can this cause problems?

https://imgur.com/a/twQFprA

Comment: How much time did pass between each test? Did you try to run it again much later? If so, what was the result? Did you check your temperatures?

Comment: Just resolved the issue! I manually set fan speed to 100% and after that I have stable 70 fps. My GPU is by default in something like silent mode and try to have maximum 60 celsius, it probably downclock itself instead to increase fan RPM. Thank you guys !!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was temperature + fan speed. I manually set fan speed to 100% and after that I have stable 70 fps. My GPU is by default in something like silent mode and try to have maximum 60 celsius, it probably downclock itself instead to increase fan RPM.